# how to observe changes in an array within controller/component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can we observe changes to an array in Ember? I have ember component that uses raw object data from a model, but to demonstrate the issue I am using array property within component itself like:

```
 init:function(){
            this._super();
            var arr = Ember.A([
                Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 1, "noOfItems": 2}),
                Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 2, "noOfItems": 3}),
                Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 3, "noOfItems": 2})]
            );
            this.set("someArray",arr);

            //DOES NOT WORK

            this.get('someArray').addArrayObserver(function () {
                Ember.ObjectController.create({
                    arrayWillChange: function (observedObj, start, removeCount, addCount) {
                        console.log("in arrayWillChange");
                    },
                    arrayDidChange: function (array, start, removeCount, addCount) {
                        console.log("in arrayDidChange");
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

I also tried :

```
testObserver: function(){
            //DOES NOT WORK
            console.log("here");
        }.observes('someArray@each')
```

But both didn't work for me!

Here is a jsbin : http://jsbin.com/EkumOjA/1/

Thanks, 
Dee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are observing a property from some object in the array use `someArray.@each.someProperty`. To observe when the array content change (someArray.pushObject, removeObject etc) use `someArray.[]` or `someArray.length`.

Also, instead of override `init` use `someFunc: function() {}.on('init')` this is the safe way to get observers working, on object initialization.

This is your updated code:

```
App.ShowQuestionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    someArray : null,
    initializeSomeArray:function(){                
        var arr = Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 1, "noOfItems": 2}),
            Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 2, "noOfItems": 3}),
            Ember.Object.create({"shelfNo": 3, "noOfItems": 2})]
        );              

        this.set("someArray",arr);
    }.on('init'), 
    testObserver: function(){                
        console.log("here");
    }.observes('someArray.[]')

});
```

And your updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/EkumOjA/2/edit

Comment: Thanks Marcio, I realized what I missed. I should have done .observes('someArray.@each') instead of .observes('someArray@each') - I missed ".". Without your jsbin I wouldn't be able to figure out my issue. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Just to remember that if you want to observer the content change, just use `someArray.[]` because the `someArray.@each` is intended to observe properties in the array, it add listerners in each item so you gain performance just using `someArray.[]`.